# Cannot Send Function In Object Javascript Using Socket IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

This Is my code client socket.io, im trying to emit data and callback to server

```js
_this.emitHandler = function(event, data, callback){

  var packet = {};
  

  if(data){

    packet.data = data;

  }

  if(callback){

    packet.callback = callback;

  }


  io.emit(event, packet); // emit packet to server with data and callback
  

}
```

and when i console.log my packet its just print data, the callback disappeared. this is my server code

```js
io.on('*', function(socket, args, next){

  console.log(args) // this args just print data in console


}
```

im using socket.io-event btw to capture all event, is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send function like that.
What you can do is to JSON.stringify it and on the server call eval() on it.

Remember that it's dangerous. Anybody could send some code to your server and execute it.

Comment: JSON.stringify cannot handle function javscript

Comment: Search for " JSON.stringify function" you will find many examples how to do that